# <eval>:32 ReferenceError: "document" is not defined javax.script.ScriptException

Tags: javascript, java, canvas, svg

I need to generate a symbol (in canvas or SVG format) using Spatial illusions javascript library and use that symbol in my java (Proprietary Framework) project. the java script code is available [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cb4fa03108b158cd16722f8a0c086904). I am using below code for the same.

```
public class TestSymbolCreation {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ScriptEngineManager scriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine scriptEngine = scriptEngineManager.getEngineByExtension("js");

        System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsoluteFile());

        File file = new File("./src/resources/milsymbol.js");
        try {

            Reader reader = new FileReader(file);
            scriptEngine.eval(reader);
            Bindings obj = (Bindings) scriptEngine.eval("var canvasElement = {value : new ms.Symbol('SFG-UCI----D',{size:35}).asCanvas() };  canvasElement;");
            Object canvas = obj.get("value");
            System.out.println("Canvas =>"+canvas);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

But I keep on getting the following exception. How to get this working? Can someone help me please?

```
javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "document" is not defined in <eval> at line number 32
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:467)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:451)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:403)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:399)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:155)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
    at TestSymbolCreation.main(TestSymbolCreation.java:30)
Caused by: <eval>:32 ReferenceError: "document" is not defined
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.error(ECMAErrors.java:57)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.referenceError(ECMAErrors.java:319)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.referenceError(ECMAErrors.java:291)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.Global.__noSuchProperty__(Global.java:1432)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$149$403515A$\^eval\_.L:1-1$L:32-8$exports(<eval>:32)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$87$\^eval\_.:program(<eval>:1)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:640)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:228)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:393)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:446)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: What is inside `./src/resources/milsymbol.js` ?

Comment: @NathanP. Its a javascript library file from https://spatialillusions.com/

Comment: Right, but you must provide the relevant code so we can help you. The exception is likely raised from this file.

Comment: @NathanP. Do you want the java script file?

Comment: @NathanP. I included gist of that js file. Please have a look

Comment: This is a minified javascript file, we won't debug it, that's way too much work... Anyway, you're running this script using `ScriptEngine`. Are you sure this class provides a `document` object ? Interpreting JavaScript is not the same as providing a full browser environment.

Answer (score 0):

This is Script executor only so it will not provide the document object as the browser provides.
To use the document object you need to integrate third party browser which can integrate with swing component e.g. JTidy